# How to solve this equation with rational exponents?

Tags: radical-equations

I've been really struggling to solve this one, could you provide how you'd solve it?

$$3x^{2/3} + 4x^{1/3} =4$$

Comment: @KM101, I suggest you post your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, notice how one term has twice the exponent of the other:

$$3x^{\color{blue}{\frac{2}{3}}}+4x^{\color{green}{\frac{1}{3}}} = 4$$

$$x^{\frac{2}{3}} = x^{2\cdot\frac{1}{3}} = \left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^2$$

So, you can rewrite the equation as

$$3\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^2+4x^{\frac{1}{3}} = 4$$

The good thing here is that you can now make the substitution $t  = x^\frac{1}{3}$ in order to reach a simple quadratic equation:

$$3t^2+4t = 4 \iff 3t^2+4t-4 = 0$$

From here, you can solve the quadratic for $t$ and finally obtain $x$. This technique is typically used for all equations of the form $ax^{2n}+bx^n+c = 0$: letting $t = x^n$ and solving $at^2+bt+c = 0$.